# Что такое IntPtr ?

Tags: c#

Зачем это нужно и как использовать?
Что означает следующая запись?

```
IntPtr pin, pout;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это целое число, представляющее собой указатель на что угодно, т.е. хранящее в себе адрес. В .NET используется специальная структура данных, а не просто int, чтобы обеспечить совместимость между 32-битными и 64-битными системами. Обычно этот тип используется для работы с импортированными функциями, которые используют указатели.

Comment: Спасибо, выходит я ошибался.